# Getting a clean working directory after `git svn clone` without modifying tracked files

Tags: git

Directly after importing a svn repository, `git status` showed a few modified lines. Apparently, someone added a `.gitattributes` file way back with `* text=auto`. After commenting this line out, `git status` shows the `.gitattributes` file as the only modified file, which is correct.

I don't want to commit this change back into the svn repository (I'm new and the only one working with git), I tried to add this file to `.git/info/exclude`, but it still showed up, same for a `.gitignore` file.

Is there a way to get a *locally* clean working directory, that does not involve editing tracked files?